# How to read this in English?

Tags: soft-question

I am a teacher of English for IT. Please, help me! I do not know how to read $s(n), y(n), e(n)$ in English.

We are studying signal processing and the way a filter operates. The sentence is:

> The incoming signal $s(n)$ is filtered or weighted in a programmable
>   filter to yield an output $y(n)$ which is then compared against a
>   desired conditioning, or training signal $y(n)$ to yield an error
>   signal, $e(n)$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $s(n)$ is read "s of n".

Comment: You can copy and paste your text to any online text to speech program (e.g [this](http://text-to-speech.imtranslator.net/)) and listen.

Comment: @achillehui But doesn't that text to speech program mispronounce $s(n)$?

Comment: $s,y$ and $e$ are most likely functions of some input $n$. Each pronounced "s of n", "y of n" and "e of n" respectively.

Comment: @littleO It is also common to simply call it "s n". I have heard both many years ago when I'm still in school. In fact, my memory tell me the simplified form "s n" is more common.

Comment: @achillehui In my native language such a program would fail miserably as we often read mathematics different from if it were a regular text. In this particular example, we could read $s(n)$ as 's of n' or 's n'. I doubt the software would read 's of n'. More blatant would be something like $x^2$.

Comment: "s n" could be mistaken for $s_n$; "s of n" is better.

Comment: Or even "The signal s(which depends on n), ..."

Answer (score 1):

I would read it as "s n", but, especially for people who can't see what you're reading, "s of n" is probably best.